# Difficulties using arrays, beginner

Tags: java, arrays

I am just learning using arrays in java. I am trying to assign an array with 10 random integers, though my code is returning arrays filled with 0's. What am I doing wrong?
Help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class E7point1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] array = new int[10];
        int i = 0;
        Random random = new Random();

        while (i < array.length)
        {
            array[i] = 1 + random.nextInt(100);
            i++;

        }
        System.out.print(array[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: @I think it the above code will throw arrayindexofboundexception

Comment: Your code seems to work fine except last line where you are trying to read `array[10]` where indexes of 10 element array are 0-9. If you want to print all elements of array iterate over again or just use `System.out.print(Arrays.toString(array));` using `java.util.Arrays`.

Comment: @Pshemo You should make that an answer, I'd upvote for just using `Arrays.toString`

Comment: @Pshemo yeah agreed with `MadProgrammer` u gave a nice description u should post that as an answer

Comment: @MadProgrammer There are lot of good answers already, with yours among  them which is at least as good as my comment :)

Answer (score 5):

The supplied code should be giving you a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because `i` will equal `10` by the time you get to `System.out.print(array[i]);`...

Instead, try using

```
// System.out.print(array[i]);
for (int ri : array) {
    System.out.println(ri);
}
```

The rest of you code seems to work fine for me...

**Updated**

As Pshemo and Thihara have pointed, you could simply use...

```
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(array));
```

But I think the use of a loop is a good learning exercise ;)

Comment: @Thihara 1- As a learning exercise, a loop is a useful; 2- I'm waiting for Pshemo to put it their answer ;)

Comment: 100% agree with @MadProgrammer. For beginner programmer it is better to start with iterations than build in methods, even if they are created precisely for this purpose. Understanding is more important now than pretty code. +1

Answer (score 2):

Use like this

```
Random r = new Random();
    // four values [0, 9]
    int[] kickerNumbers={r.nextInt(10), r.nextInt(10), r.nextInt(10), r.nextInt(10)};
    // one value [0, 4]
    int kickerPowerball = r.nextInt(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

...or you can modify your while loop:

```
@Test


public void testGenerateRandomNumbers() throws Exception {
        int[] array = new int[10];
        int i = 0;
        Random random = new Random();

        while (i < array.length)
        {
            array[i] = 1 + random.nextInt(100);
            System.out.println(array[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }
```

But MadProgrammer's suggestion is better :)

Comment: review you answer. It will not fill full array length and what he is trying to do is print full array not the one element.

Answer (score 0):

It will give you `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` as i value becomes 10.

In place of `System.out.print(array[i]);` use

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    System.out.print(array[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        int i = 0;
        int[] array = new int[10];

        while (i < array.length) {
            array[i] = 1 + random.nextInt(100);
            System.out.println(array[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class E7point1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try{
        int[] array = new int[10];
        int i = 0;
        Random random = new Random();

        while (i < array.length)
        {
            array[i] = 1 + random.nextInt(100);
            i++;

        }
        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(array));}
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**output**

```
[29, 84, 73, 73, 93, 94, 69, 79, 1, 76]
```

Comment: `exception handling` - you dont need it here

Comment: @sansix as per OP's orginal code it was throwing exception as i have commented.

Comment: yeah that was due to OP's buggy code - but since you are using `Arrays.toString(array)` you don't need exception handling here